# Does a wood elf's Mask of the Wild feature allow hiding in plain sight in dim light/darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, vision-and-light, stealth, elf

Can a wood elf hide in plain sight in dim light/darkness?

Why I believe this could be the case:

The wood elf Mask of the Wild description says:

> You can attempt to hide even when you are only lightly obscured by foliage, heavy rain, falling snow, mist, and other natural phenomena.

Dim light (dusk) and darkness are both "natural phenomena", right?

So following this logic, could a wood elf, RAW, hide in plain sight in dim light conditions (e.g. dim light shed by a torch in a dungeon), or in darkness against creatures with dark vision (e.g. against orks with dark vision in a dark dungeon), who treat darkness as dim light according to RAW.